# Mysql: get json array length and ignore null values

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have this query

```
select json_length(data->"$.row.*.code") as count from hospitalization_history where id = 238
```

The result in count is 8, because `data->"$.row.*.code"` returns `["J00.00", "V01.00", "G00.00", null, null, null, null, null]`;

How can I a get number of not null values in json array?

Comment: Parse your array to the rowset then count non-`null` values. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd0a37bb25d526f029a7a82c6a1fe0cc

Comment: @Akina I posted your comment as a community wiki.

Comment: @Scratte I am not sure that my code is applicable to OP's server (its version may be too old) - in this case the solution must be altered.

Comment: @Akina I see. I hadn't thought of that. If they reply that it's not working for them, or if you'd rather post an Answer yourself. I'll delete it. I just came upon your comment and played with it and learned something new myself :)

Comment: @Akina seems like your solution works for MySQL 8.0.24+. I have 8.0.16 and get 8 as a result

Comment: *seems like your solution works for MySQL 8.0.24+.* No, JSON_TABLE() which is the most "young" option in the query was introduced since 8.0.4. So it **must** work in your 8.0.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, found this solution for MySQL 8+:

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(
    JSON_SEARCH('["J00.00", "V01.00", "G00.00", null, null, null]','all','%')
) AS count;
```

[Try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=824c653fff39bcc422ed8f5d49f00097)

Answer (score 1):

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67212345/mysql-how-to-get-json-array-length-and-ignore-null-values#comment118803300_67212345) from [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) says to

> Parse your array to the rowset then count non-null values. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd0a37bb25d526f029a7a82c6a1fe0cc

The SQL in the fiddle is:

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT '["J00.00", "V01.00", "G00.00", null, null, null, null, null]' jstr)
SELECT COUNT(val)
FROM cte
JOIN JSON_TABLE(cte.jstr,
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (val VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jtable
```

Results in

| COUNT(val) |
| --- |
| 3 |

Comment: I've tested this on MySQL 8.0.16 and the result is 8

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy You may want to ping Akina in a comment on the Question and let them know. You should update your Question with the version, you are using as well.